# How to update and with join table in php query?

Tags: php, mysql, join, sql-update

I was trying to do update operation where in the where clause it will follow the session id of the user.

Below is the code that I have tried.

```
if(isset($_POST['withdraw']))
{ 
   
   $sql="
   UPDATE s
      SET s.status ='Claimed'
        , s.Date = CURRENT_DATE()
     FROM sales s
     JOIN user u
       ON s.No = u.No
    WHERE s.DATE(TransacDate) != CURRENT_DATE()
      AND s.status = 'Unclaimed'
      AND u.No = '". $_SESSION["No"]."'
    ORDER 
       BY s.TransacDate
   ";
   $sql_claim = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
   
   if (mysqli_affected_rows($link) > 0){
    echo "<script>alert('Successfully Claimed!')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location = 'claimed.php'</script>";  
   }
  else
    echo "<script>alert('Please try tomorrow!')</script>";
}
```

I was trying to achieve a result where user can claim their money if their transaction is not today. based on their session. Which in the session has id. With the current query I don't get any error but I believe it is because it did not receive the id. How do I fix this query?

Answer (score 1):

You should define your table name first and then join it

```
$sql="UPDATE sales s
      JOIN user u ON s.No = u.No
      SET s.status ='Claimed', s.Date = CURRENT_DATE()
      WHERE s.DATE(s.TransacDate) != CURRENT_DATE()
      AND s.status = 'Unclaimed'
      AND u.No = '". $_SESSION["No"]."'
      ORDER BY s.TransacDate";
```

> Warning: You are wide open to SQL Injections and should use
> parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your
> queries. They are provided by PDO or by MySQLi. Never trust any kind
> of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users,
> you are still in risk of corrupting your data. Escaping is not enough!